# Is it true to save JSON to NSUserDefaults and populate ableview from there?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist, nsuserdefaults

in my app i fetch some data from a server and save it into NSUserDefaults and want to populate the TableView with some elements from that data(my tableview is a different class to my class in which i send the GET and bring data). But as i googled i can't be sure if i'm doing right. As i see from googling(and from this site) this is not the best way but i can't be sure.. So, can some one give me an idea about the way to "populate tableview in a different class with some results of JSON response which created in a different class"?

Note-1: If your suggestion is .plist please give some samplecode about how to do.

Note-2: I use ios 5 but don't use ARC in my project

Comment: Those who have given minuses please can any one make an explanation about why they did this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing something like this I would recommend looking into Core Data for storing you data, and pulling it out in whichever class you need it. Would also suggest using the open source JSON library:

http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

in order to parse the JSON that you have an store it into you Core Data model as valid objects. If you have not used Core Data before I used this tutorial when I started, it was really good:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

It's worth going through the whole thing before you start. I know its a pain having to learn something new if you haven't used it before, but this id definitely the way to be doing it. And Core Data is so powerful, handy and simple when you know how to use!

Hope this is of some help to you :)